# Spring Security - how to list objects by different Users

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm wondering about how to filter Objects based on specific Users and how to give some User the auth to view just some objects with Spring Security.
I mean, I have a Park.java object which links via Hibernate to a park table.
Then I have User.java which are the classical User for Spring Security. I want to assign only some parks to each user so that each user can access and see only the Parks he has the auth to.

I was thinking of creating a ManyToMany relation between Park.java and User.java so to have the possibility to assign parks to users.

So User.java has

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_parcheggio", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="park_id") })
    private Set<Park> parks = new HashSet<Park>();

    public Set<Park> getParks() {
        return parks;
    }

    public void setParks(Set<Park> parks){
        this.parks = parks;
    }
```

And Park.java has

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="park")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

Once created the relations between users and parks, how can I be sure that every logged user can only see parks he has the auth to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to validate if the requested `Park` belongs to the user. From your controller you can check the user by so:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
```

From `Park` you can validate if the `User` is valid and take actions upon that.